# Form partitioning buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a form like this but unable to get the name of a grid surrounding the Add new Record i.e. small grid which carries the buttons "Add New" ,"Save","Cancel".So ,please tell me the name of the tool in tool box which partitions form like this.

[image: Form to get and insert data from database]

Comment: Not quite understand, you want to know the tool name which is showing border with text 'Add New Record'. It is GroupBox.

Comment: @YograjGupta I think you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a [GroupBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupbox(v=vs.110).aspx).